# UpdateException when using SQL Server Compact with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to use Entity Framework with SQL Server Compact. I can perform reading such as :

```
var context = new TestEntities();

foreach (var p in context.Personnes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.prenom + " " + p.nom);
}
```

but I can't perform insert :

```
var context = new TestEntities();

context.Personnes.AddObject(new Personne() {nom = "Test", prenom = "Test" });

context.SaveChanges();
```

An `UpdateException` is raised when I try to do this. The `Personne` table has just 3 columns: `id (int, primary key), nom (varchar) and prenom (varchar).`

Here is the display I have when I run the program :

> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException:
>   Une erreur s'est produite lors de la
>   préparation de la définition de la
>   commande. Pour plus de détails,
>   consultez l'exception interne. --->
>   System.NotSupportedException: Les clès
>   et les valeurs générées par le serveur
>   ne sont pas prises en charge par SQL
>   Server Compact.
>
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateInsertSql(DbInsertCommandTree
>   tree, List`1& parameters, Boolean
>   isLocalProvider)
>          … System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.SqlGenerator.GenerateSql(DbCommandTree
>   tree, List`1& parameters, CommandType&
>   commandType, Boolean isLocalProvider)
>          … System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbCommandTree
>   commandTree)
>          … System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbCommandTree
>   commandTree)
>          … System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree
>   commandTree)
>          … System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree
>   commandTree)
>          … System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree
>   commandTree)
>          --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
>          … System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree
>   commandTree)
>          … System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues)
>          … System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnection
>   connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1
>   generatedValues)
>          … System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)

Thank you :)

Comment: So is this a contest to guess what the error was, or would you like to share it with us and maybe get an answer?

Comment: English is main language here, please translate error text to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlServer Compact doesn't support server-side key generation. You must generate key on application side. So set `id` explicitly. Here is example.

```
context.Personnes.AddObject(new Personne() {id = lastId++, nom = "Test", prenom = "Test" });
```

You have to maintain `lastId`. Code that I wrote above will work only in single thread.